# Refs mongo dont working nestjs with graphql

Tags: mongodb, graphql, nestjs

I believe I am missing something I already tried to add populate but it doesn't work either I don't know what it is and I can't find any examples about relationships

I want to select many items for one user.

In items it references user but in user items[] returns blank and array is empty in mongo

Users Module

```
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }])],
```

UserSchema

```
export const UsersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    [...]
    items: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Items'}],
});
```

Items module

```
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Item', schema: ItemSchema }]),
],
```

ItemSchema

```
export const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    description: String,
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'},
});
```

Mutation to create item in items.resolver.ts

```
  @Mutation(() => ItemType)
  async createItem(@Args('input') input: ItemInput): Promise<ItemInput> {
    return this.itemsService.create(input);
  }
```

and service with create method

```
  async create(createItemDto: ItemInput): Promise<ItemType> {
    const createdItem = new this.itemModel(createItemDto);
    return await createdItem.save();
  }
```

Item reference in users only shows an empty array in mongo, but my user reference in items shows object id as below

[image]

[image]

Comment: you add populate?

Comment: @GiovanniDias yes, but does not work

Comment: try using a debugger and see what is being passed at the end for items to mongo?